# html/hta mutiple file in audio player

Tags: html, audio, syntax, hta

ok so i started coding a .hta application , pretty much a html page with .hta extension , i adde this mp3 player and it did work

```html
<object data="test.mp3" type="audio/mp3" width="200" height="40">
<param name="src" value="test.mp3">
<param name="autostart" value="0">
</object>
```

but it's one song playing again and again , so plz is there any way to add multiple files to the playlist i believe it's something that should be added to "src" parameters but not sure, as i'm just starting i did add "," in between , and i tried also ";" none of them was working so i'm waiting for answers :D

i also wanna know if someone can show me how to become familiar with  tag i see it's very helpful and powerful for activeX, audio,video,pdf .... files so i'm just waiting so impatiently [i don't know much about object, so plz plz be more clear]

Answer (score 2):

Get inspired by this example **HTA_Audio_Player.hta**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hackoo Audio Player with Playlist by Hackoo 2014</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
      ID = "Music"
      icon="http://files.softicons.com/download/social-media-icons/free-large-twitter-icons-by-aha-soft/ico/Audio.ico"
      APPLICATIONNAME="Music"
      SCROLL="no"
      navigable="no"
      selection="no"
      showintaskbar="yes"
      singleinstance="no"
      innerborder="no"
      maximizebutton="no"
      minimizebutton="yes"
      border="dialog"
      borderstyle="normal"
      caption="yes"
      contextMenu="no"
      sysmenu="yes"
 >
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">
   <script>
      function loadSong(elt,e) {
    if(!e) var e = window.event;
    document.getElementById("player").src=elt.href;
    document.getElementById("player").load();
        document.getElementById("player").play();
    return false;
      }

      window.onload = function() {
    links = document.getElementById("playlist").getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i = 0; i<links.length; i++) {
      links[i].onclick=function(e) { return loadSong(this, e); };
    }
      }
   </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #player {
    margin: 10;
    padding: 10;
        font-family: sans;
        font-size: 12px;
    width: 400px;
      }
      #playlist {
    border: solid 5px #555;
    font-family: sans;
    font-size: 14px;
        background-color: #777;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 200px;
      }
      #playlist li:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #888;
      }
      #playlist li:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #777;
      }
      #signature {
        border: solid 5px #555;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        font-family: sans;
        font-size: 12px;
        background-color: #888;
        color: white;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 200px;
      }
      #playlist li a,
      #playlist li a:visited,
      #playlist li a:hover {
        color: white;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="design_encoder" href="&#0104;&#0116;&#0116;&#0112;&#0058;//&#0104;&#0097;&#0099;&#0107;&#0111;&#0111;&#0046;&#0097;&#0108;&#0119;&#0097;&#0121;&#0115;&#0100;&#0097;&#0116;&#0097;&#0046;&#0110;&#0101;&#0116;/&#0100;&#0101;&#0115;&#0105;&#0103;&#0110;&#0095;&#0101;&#0110;&#0099;&#0111;&#0100;&#0101;&#0114;&#0046;&#0099;&#0115;&#0115;"/>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
  window.resizeTo x,y
  iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
  itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
  window.moveTo ileft, itop
 End Sub

 Sub Window_Onload
 CenterWindow 440,470
 End Sub
</script>
<body>
<DIV id="Splash" STYLE="background-image:url(http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/laser.gif); background-position:center center; background-repeat:no-repeat; align=center; cursor: hand; Height:300;Width:400;Border:0.1mm solid black;">
<center>
  <marquee DIRECTION="UP" HEIGHT="330" WIDTH="350" SCROLLAMOUNT="2" title="Listen to The Best Music">
   <center><font face="Comic sans MS" color=RED size=6 STYLE ="cursor: hand;"><b>DJ Hackoo for you on the Mix</b></font></center>
     <br><br>
    <center><font face="Comic sans MS" color=RED size=3 STYLE ="cursor: hand;">Music for ever</b></font></center>
    <br><center><font face="Comic sans MS" color=RED  size=3 STYLE ="cursor: hand;">DJ © Hackoo 2014<br><br></font></center>
    <br><center><img src="http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/DJ2.gif"></center>
    <br><center><img src="http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/DJ3.gif"></center>
    <br><center><img src="http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/DJ4.gif"></center>
    <br><center><img src="&#104;&#116;&#116;&#112;&#58;&#47;&#47;&#110;&#115;&#109;&#48;&#53;&#46;&#99;&#97;&#115;&#105;&#109;&#97;&#103;&#101;&#115;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;&#47;&#105;&#109;&#103;&#47;&#50;&#48;&#49;&#49;&#47;&#48;&#55;&#47;&#50;&#51;&#47;&#47;&#49;&#49;&#48;&#55;&#50;&#51;&#48;&#55;&#52;&#49;&#52;&#48;&#49;&#51;&#49;&#49;&#48;&#52;&#56;&#53;&#48;&#54;&#52;&#49;&#57;&#46;&#103;&#105;&#102;"></center>
    </marquee>
 </center>
 </DIV>
 </center>
<center>
<div id="Player"></div>
<SPAN ID="ONSCR"></SPAN></DIV></CENTER>
<center><div> <audio tabindex="0" id="player" preload="load" controls="" src="http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Intro_DJ.mp3" autoplay></audio>
<ul id="playlist">
  <li><a href="http://radio.mosaiquefm.net:8000/mosalive">Radio Mosaique FM</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/David_Guetta_Miami_2014.mp3">David Guetta Miami_2014</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Best of Avicii Megamix 2014.mp3">Avicii Megamix 2014</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Megamix 90.mp3">Megamix les annees 90s</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="signature"> by © Hackoo 2014</ul>
</div>
</center>
</body></html>
```

Comment: this is something from another level tho ! actually i' don't know anything about Jscript , and i just started html coding so my knowledge is poor , i guess i understood every command line there but that is some awesome work man, congratulation

Answer (score 1):

well seem that i'll be waiting so long, but at the end i found a solution , actually i'm now using a flash mp3 player (a .swf file) which has the option to make a playlist . if you're interested in knowing the code it goes like this :

```
<object data="mp3-player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="40">
  <param name="movie" value="mp3-player.swf">
  <param name="flashvars" value="mp3=mp3file1.mp3|mp3file2.mp3|mp3file3.mp3...&amp;volume=100">
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

i believe if you have another flash mp3 player you may wanna change the values in "flashvars" according to what flash file you have :D
thx for the 11 views :D :D