# HTA plays sounds but stops playing them until I restart my computer

Tags: hta

I have an HTA interface that I'm working on. When I click a button I want a sound to be played each time that I click that button, without looping, and it does it just fine at first, but shortly after it doesn't play the sound anymore when I click the button, even after restarting the application, and it won't play again until after I restart my computer.

Here is the general layout of the function I call:

```
function playSound() {
    var mySound= new Audio('Sounds/mySound.mp3');
    mySound.loop = false;
    mySound.play();
};
```

Any ideas?

PS. this is my first post, so please let me know if I should change anything about this post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Take a look at this ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547902/html-hta-mutiple-file-in-audio-player?answertab=active#tab-top